# How do I debug CSS, when a style is applied to element on :hover over element's parent (preferably in Firebug)?

Tags: html, css, web, firebug

I want to inspect CSS style of a list, applied by `ul li:hover > ul {}` rule in Firebug.

So the trick with checkbox on ":hover" won't work, cause I have to hover the inspected element's parent, not the element itself.[image]

How do I inspect style applied to that kind of element? Is there any way I could move to the style panel with a hotkey, while holding the mouse over element's parent? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing I managed to do is painfully and patiently Tab the focus to Style subwindow. It worked, but I wish there was a better way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I just released a tool that you can use to easily view the layout of all of your elements - even in their hover state.

[HTML Box Visualizer - GitHub](https://github.com/ghmcadams/boxvis)